# Questions about billing and business practices

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I have a question about billing practices for a freelance designer but don't know if that is within the scope of the site.

Specifically, my question would be something like: "How should I charge a client if I work really fast?"

It seems like it would fit, but I'm not finding any other business types of questions like it here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My opinion: Absolutely! I can think of one billing question in the past that got lots of attention: [**Bill a client for a design error?**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/17731/8708)

[client-relations](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client-relations) might be good to use, but we've also got [business](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) that would possible be appropriate as well.