# Modifying questions that are very popular

Tags: discussion

This question got a lot of attention and had 2 questions in it, which are related:

[Selling a logo to a business who did not ask for one](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/68569/selling-a-logo-to-a-business-who-did-not-ask-for-one)

The first one was about a strategy to sell a logo made during a school project. The second was about how to estimate the price to ask for it.

The second part was deleted by another user with this comment:

> Removed off-topic question about how much to sell for. It is specific
>   to the current date, geographical location, and simply not objectively
>   answerable. We cannot value a logo based on this information, **and
>   should not be doing it here anyway**.

Yet, one very big network question and other meta seem to allow price questions or at least allow them within a clear context or when requesting guidelines.

[What price should I charge for design services?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/957/what-price-should-i-charge-for-design-services)

[Should fee and price questions go on the Freelancing Stack?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/should-fee-and-price-questions-go-on-the-freelancing-stack)

[Questions about billing and business practices](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/678/questions-about-billing-and-business-practices?rq=1)

**What bothers me is that second price part was answered in a lot of the 7 answers on this popular question.** I thought pricing questions were still acceptable here, within limits.

---

Can we tone down the editing on popular network questions when it's not really necessary and when answers have already been posted about what was deleted? What to do in that kind of situation?

Comment: Honestly not sure if this warranted a meta post considering the anecdotal example, or is this happening more often? This would be a good discussion to have with the user who made the edit and may be a good time to educate if they are objectively in the wrong. That being said I think there's something to be said about editing a question's meaning after a number of answers have already addressed it pre-edit. Though that should be independent of the popularity of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I honestly think the part about the price was off-topic.

Questions about pricing aren't necessarily off topic—as seen by the other question and discussions you referenced—but there is a significant difference. The question you reference (and the questions linked to from the discussions you reference) are more generally about strategies, practices and pricing in general.

The part of the edited question that was removed was asking for a *specific price* recommendation for a *specific piece of work*. That is impossible to answer. At least objectively, without making a lot of assumptions. You could give general advice about how to price the work but that part of the question was 8 words. If that was asked on its own as a question, it would have been closed as too-broad, without a doubt.

The fact that existing answers talk about the price is neither here nor there, in my opinion. It is very related to the general question (*Selling* is in the title) so the edit doesn't invalidate any of those answers.

I'm not 100% sure wether I think it should have been edited out or not. It is related to the question as a whole, but if you are going to think of them as two separate questions... that one is off-topic. I'm not sure it's a big issue either way.

---

*Just to note: I completely agreed with you when I first read this post—until I read back through the edit and existing answers and changed my mind. So I think your general point is valid—I just don't think it's a problem in this case.*

Comment: I totally agree it would be off-topic or too broad by itself. But it was asked in a clear context in this case and the OP is member for 2 days so that part of the question was asked in a simple way. The issue is parts of the answers now look like "commentary" about pricing, and I remember members voicing their concerns about answers having "commentary" content that shouldn't be there.

Comment: I get your point, I do. But I don't think it makes any part of the answers commentary. The question is about selling something and price is obviously a part of that. Maybe that sentence should have been reworded instead to be less about a specific price and more about a general pricing strategy. I don't know... It's late here and I'm tired!

Comment: "Pricing strategy" is a very appropriate and flexible way to ask for this indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever something is off-topic it has real potential to invite more off-topic questions.

In order to stem the flow of off-topicness we need to remove off-topic content.

The fact that it was popular gave more reason to prune it, because SE users who aren't familiar with GDSE guidelines may think it's acceptable to ask such questions here and may get offended when their question is closed, if this one is kept open.

I did take the fact that some answers referred to it into consideration, but as has been discussed before - *we should not be forced to keep off-topic content just because someone answered it*.

Even if it was on-topic, which it isn't, how can we value a logo with **zero** information about it?

I hope that answers all of your questions.

Comment: The main point is: it's not considered off-topic in the context (see urls I added to my post). Most active users with the "close" privilege who review question use their critical thinking when a question is only "how much do I charge". In that context, I think the sentence could have simply been modified to "pricing strategy" for example, as CAI suggested. The edit was not necessary in my opinion and according to previous meta discussions. And this answer doesn't really mention what to do when unnecessary edits are made.

Comment: @go-junta see the end of my post for the other valid reason for removal "*Even if it was on-topic ... how can we value a logo with zero information about it?*" We don't know what industry it is, what the aims were, what country they're in, and we have existing questions that ask how to price.

Comment: There was info about it: from a student, pre-made, no revisions so far, etc. You wouldn't be able to give a price knowing the data you mentioned anyway because pricing is very personal & has too many variables to consider (and you can't know about them all, everywhere in the world)! Price questions are ALWAYS about pricing strategy, no one can give precise pricing and no one can absolutely judge a logo value even by looking at it. But we can give price ranges, tips, guidelines on how to evaluate the value of the work. From what I understand, that's why some pricing questions are not off-topic.

Comment: Anyway, the topic is becoming "are pricing questions off-topic" now, while my main point is "what to do when edits have been made on topics that are not judged off-topic in context". So maybe you can open a new meta post about acceptable pricing questions (or why/when you think it's off-topic). I guess I can simply re-edit the question if I want to and people can vote to close it if it makes it an off-topic question!

Comment: @go-junta reediting it to a close worthy state would be an incorrect edit. As it stands it is perfectly on topic. With the additional question it is controversial. The additional question adds little to no value. It might as well be left in an entirely acceptable state, rather than stir up a discussion that doesn't really need to happen.